# Pagination with $this->db->query() and $this->db->limit()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I tried the following code for pagination but it not works for me it not shows 10 records per page it shows all records on the single page and again same number of records shows on the next page my code in controller

```
<?php 
class Classified_detail extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('Jobseekermodel','',TRUE);
        //$this->load->database($config);
        //$secound_db= $this->load->database('classified_db', TRUE);
        //$CI =   &get_instance();
        $this->db2 = $this->load->database('classified_db', TRUE); //doolaly
        $this->load->model('Emailmodel','',TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Bookmodel','',TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Consultantmodel','',TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Openingmodel','',TRUE);
        //$this->load->model('classified/Mobile_model','',TRUE);
        $this->load->model('classified/classified_ad','',TRUE);
        $this->load->model('classified/create_ad','',TRUE);
        $this->load->model('Commfuncmodel','',TRUE);
        $this->lang->load('message', 'english');
        $this->lang->load('mail', 'english');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        if (session_id() == "") session_start();
    }

    /***********************Start of Function For Showing list of ebooks from database **********************************/      
    function index($msg=NULL)
    {   
        $this->Commfuncmodel->checkJobseekerLogin();

        //******My expired ads*******/

        //post ad history
        $_SESSION["ex_ad_paging"] = PER_PAGE_RECORDS;
        $today = date('Y-m-d');
        $qry ="select AM.Ad_Title as Title,AM.Advertizement_Text as Description,AM.Price,AMP.Expiry_Date 
        from ad_mobile_phones AM inner join ad_mobilephone_plan_mapping AMP on
        AM.Ad_ID=AMP.Ad_ID
        where AM.Created_By='".$_SESSION['jobseeker_id']."' and AMP.Expiry_Date <'".$today."'
        UNION
        select A.Title,A.Description,A.Price,B.Expiry_Date from ad_vehicle A inner join ad_vehicle_plan_mapping B 
on A.Ad_ID = B.Ad_ID where A.Created_By ='".$_SESSION['jobseeker_id']."' and B.Expiry_Date <'".$today."'";

            $query=$this->db->query($qry);

            $ex_ed_count=$query->num_rows();
            $ex_ad_data=$query->result_array();


        /******************Start of Pagination****************/
        $segments = array('classified/classified_detail','index/my_ex_ads');
        $url_name=site_url($segments);
        $ex_ed_count = count($ex_ad_data); 
        $per_page_records=((@$_SESSION["ex_ad_paging"]=="All")?$ex_ed_count:@$_SESSION["ex_ad_paging"]);
$expagination=$this->Commfuncmodel->pagination_a($ex_ed_count,$this->uri->segment(5),$per_page_records,$url_name,"1","EXAD");
        /******************End Pagination******************/

        if($this->uri->segment(4)== "my_ex_ads")
        { 
            $page_no=(int)$this->uri->segment(5);
            if( empty($page_no) || ( $page_no <1 ) )
                $nextrecord = 0 ;
            else
                $nextrecord = ($page_no-1) * @$_SESSION["ex_ad_paging"] ;
        }       
            if($_SESSION["ex_ad_paging"]!="All")
            {
                    $limit_start=$nextrecord;
                    $limit_end=$_SESSION["ex_ad_paging"];
            }
            else
            {
                $limit_start=0;
                $limit_end=$ex_ed_count;
            }

        $qry ="select AM.Ad_Title as Title,AM.Advertizement_Text as Description,AM.Price,AMP.Expiry_Date 
        from ad_mobile_phones AM inner join ad_mobilephone_plan_mapping AMP on
        AM.Ad_ID=AMP.Ad_ID where AM.Created_By='".$_SESSION['jobseeker_id']."' and AMP.Expiry_Date <'".$today."'
        UNION
        select A.Title,A.Description,A.Price,B.Expiry_Date from ad_vehicle A inner join ad_vehicle_plan_mapping B 
on A.Ad_ID = B.Ad_ID where A.Created_By ='".$_SESSION['jobseeker_id']."' and B.Expiry_Date <'".$today."'";
            //$this->db->limit(@$limit_end,@$limit_start);
            //var_dump($limit_end);
            //var_dump($limit_start);
            $query=$this->db->query($qry);
            $this->db->limit(@$limit_end,@$limit_start);
            //var_dump($query);
            $my_ad_data=$query->result_array(); 
            //old data
            //$this->db2->where('Expiry_Date' < $date);

//          $this->db2->limit(@$limit_end,@$limit_start);
            //$query=$this->db2->get(ad_mobilephone_plan_mapping);

//          $my_ad_data=$query->result_array(); 
            //follw up
            $i=0;
            if($query->num_rows()>0)
            {
                foreach($my_ad_data as $item => $v)
                {
                    //$my_ad_data[$i]['applied_js']="y";
                    //follow up mail sent
                    //$this->db2->where("Ad_ID",$my_ad_data[$i]['Ad_ID']);
                    //$this->db2->where('Expiry_Date' < $date);
                    //$query=$this->db2->get(ad_mobilephone_plan_mapping);
                    //var_dump($fquery);
                    //$my_ad_data[$i]['count'] = $fquery->num_rows();
                    $qry ="select AM.Ad_Title as Title,AM.Advertizement_Text as Description,AM.Price,AMP.Expiry_Date 
        from ad_mobile_phones AM inner join ad_mobilephone_plan_mapping AMP on
        AM.Ad_ID=AMP.Ad_ID where AM.Created_By='".$_SESSION['jobseeker_id']."' and AMP.Expiry_Date <'".$today."'
        UNION
        select A.Title,A.Description,A.Price,B.Expiry_Date from ad_vehicle A inner join ad_vehicle_plan_mapping B 
on A.Ad_ID = B.Ad_ID where A.Created_By ='".$_SESSION['jobseeker_id']."' and B.Expiry_Date <'".$today."'";
                    $fquery = $this->db->query($qry);
                    //var_dump($fquery);
                    //var_dump($my_ad_data[$i]['count']);
                    $my_ad_data[$i]['count'] = $fquery->num_rows();
                    if($fquery->num_rows() < 2)
                    {
                        $my_ad_data[$i]['sent_follow']="y";
                    }

                    $oid = substr($my_ad_data[$i]['opening_id'],-9);
                    $my_ad_data[$i]['oid'] = substr($oid,0,-1);

                    $i++;
                }
            }
            $data['acc'] = 'acc';
            $data['page_no'] = $page_no;
            $data['ex_ad_data'] = $my_ad_data;
            $data['ex_ed_count'] = $ex_ed_count;
            $data['expagination'] =$expagination;
            $data['nextrecord'] = $nextrecord;
            $data['msg_display'] =$msg_display;
            $data['view_file'] = 'classified/account';
            if($this->uri->segment(4)=="h")
            {
                $data['ajax'] = 1;
                $this->load->view('account/historylist',$data);
            }
            else if($this->uri->segment(4)=="my_ads")
            {
                $data['ajax'] = 1;
                $this->load->view('classified/classified_ads',$data);
            }
            else if($this->uri->segment(4)=="my_ex_ads")
            {
                $data['ajax'] = 1;
                $this->load->view('account/expired_ads',$data);
            }
            else if($this->uri->segment(4)=="job")
            {
                $data['ajax'] = 1;
                $this->load->view('account/joblist',$data);
            }
            else
            {               
                $this->load->view('classified/classified_layout',$data);
            }
    }
```

Please help me and thanks in advance

Model Commfuncmodel.php

```
<?php
class Commfuncmodel extends CI_Model
{

     function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //$this->load->model('Adminmodel','',TRUE);
    }


     function getcounter($tblnm,$id,$val)
     {
         $this->db->select('counter'); 
         $this->db->where($id,$val);
         $query = $this->db->get($tblnm);
         $data=$query->result_array();
         return $data[0];
     }

     function setcounter($tblnm,$id,$val)
     {
        $cnt = $this->getcounter($tblnm,$id,$val);
        $data['counter'] = $cnt['counter'] + 1;
        $this->db->where($id, $val);
        $this->db->update($tblnm,$data);
        return true;
     }
    /**************************PAGINATION FUNCTION START*************************************/
    function pagination($total_rec, $current_page=0, $perPage, $url_name)
    {
        $pagination = "" ; 
        //echo $current_page;
        // if total records are less than per page record then dont show pagination
        if($total_rec<= $perPage)
        {
            return ;
        }

        // Retrieve Current Page number 
        if($current_page < 0 || $current_page==0)
        {
            $p = 1 ;
        }
        else
        {
            $p = $current_page ;
        }

        //  Calculate Total Pages
        $total_pages = (int)($total_rec/$perPage) ;
        if( ($total_rec%$perPage) > 0 )
        {
            $total_pages++ ;
        }
        //echo "total pages ".$total_pages;
        //echo "p is ".$p;
        //  To show pagination
        if($total_pages >= 1)
        {
            $pagination .= '<ul class="pagination" style="margin-left:150px;">';
            //$pagination .= "<br>Showing Page ".$p." of ".$total_pages."<br>";
            //  FIRST & PRIV LINKS
            if($p>1)
            {
                //$pagination .= "<a href='".$url_name."/1'>"."First"."</a>&nbsp;" ;
                $pagination .= "<li><a style='color: #000;' href='".$url_name."/". ($p-1) ."'>"." Prev"."</a></li>" ;   
            }

            // Middle links..

            if( ($p%BEFORE_AFTER_NO) == 0)
            {
                if( ($total_pages - $p) > BEFORE_AFTER_NO)
                {
                    $start = $p-BEFORE_AFTER_NO ? $p-BEFORE_AFTER_NO:1 ;
                }

                else
                {
                    $start = $total_pages - TOTAL_PAGINATION_NO;
                    if($start <= 0)
                    {
                        $start = 1 ;
                    }   
                }   

                $end = $p+BEFORE_AFTER_NO ;
            }
            else
            {   
                if($p > 9)
                {
                    if( ($total_pages - $p) > BEFORE_AFTER_NO)
                    {
                        $start = $p - BEFORE_AFTER_NO ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $start = $total_pages - TOTAL_PAGINATION_NO;
                    }       
                $end = $p + BEFORE_AFTER_NO ;
                }
                else
                {    
                $start = 1 ;

                $end = TOTAL_PAGINATION_NO;

                }   
            }   
            for($i=$start; $i<=$end && $i<=$total_pages;$i++)
            {
                if($i==$p)
                {
                    $pagination .= '<li class="active"><a href="'.$url_name.'/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>' ;
                }

                else
                {   
                    $pagination .= "<li><a style='color: #000;' href='".$url_name."/". $i ."'>".$i."</a></li>" ;
                }   
            }
            //  NEXT & LAST links
            if($p>=1 && $p<$total_pages)
            {
                $pagination .= "<li ><a style='color: #000;' href='".$url_name ."/". ($p+1) ."'>"."Next"."</a></li>" ;
                //$pagination .= "<a href='".$url_name ."/$total_pages'>"."Last"."</a>&nbsp;" ;
            }
        }   //  if($total_pages>1) end.

        $pagination .='</ul>' ;

        return ($pagination) ;
    }

    function pagination_a($total_rec, $current_page=0, $perPage, $url_name,$ajaxflag=NULL,$d)
    {
        $pagination = "" ; 
        // if total records are less than per page record then dont show pagination
        if($total_rec<= $perPage)
        {
            return ;
        }

        // Retrieve Current Page number 
        if($current_page<0 || $current_page==0)
        {
            $p = 1 ;
        }
        else
        {
            $p = $current_page ;
        }

        //  Calculate Total Pages
        $total_pages = (int)($total_rec/$perPage) ;
        if( ($total_rec%$perPage) > 0 )
        {
            $total_pages++ ;
        }

        //  To show pagination
        if($total_pages >= 1)
        {
            $pagination .= '<ul class="pagination" style="margin-left:227px;">';
            //  FIRST & PRIV LINKS
            if($p>1)
            {

                if($ajaxflag)
                {
                    //$pagination .= "<a href=javascript:ajaxPagination('".$url_name."/1')>".lang("FIRST")."</a>&nbsp;" ;
                    $pagination .= "<li><a href=javascript:ajaxPagination('".$url_name."/". ($p-1) ."/".$d."')>"."PREV"."</a></li>" ;   
                }
                else
                {
                    //$pagination .= "<a href='".$url_name."/1'>".lang("FIRST")."</a>&nbsp;" ;
                    $pagination .= "<li><a href='".$url_name."/". ($p-1) ."'>"."PREV"."</a></li>" ; 
                }
            }

            // Middle links..
            //echo $total_pages;
            if( ($p%BEFORE_AFTER_NO) == 0)
            {
                if( ($total_pages - $p) > BEFORE_AFTER_NO)
                {
                    $start = $p-BEFORE_AFTER_NO ? $p-BEFORE_AFTER_NO:1 ;
                }

                else
                {
                    $start = $total_pages - TOTAL_PAGINATION_NO;
                    if($start <= 0)
                    {
                        $start = 1 ;
                    }   
                }   

                $end = $p+BEFORE_AFTER_NO ;
            }
            else
            {   
                if($p > 9)
                {
                    if( ($total_pages - $p) > BEFORE_AFTER_NO)
                    {
                        $start = $p - BEFORE_AFTER_NO ;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $start = $total_pages - TOTAL_PAGINATION_NO;
                    }       
                $end = $p + BEFORE_AFTER_NO ;
                }
                else
                {    
                $start = 1 ;

                $end = TOTAL_PAGINATION_NO;

                }   
            }   
            for($i=$start; $i<=$end && $i<=$total_pages;$i++)
            {
                if($i==$p)
                {
                    $pagination .= '<li class="active"><a class="page-links" id="current">'.$i.'</a></li> ' ;
                }

                else
                {   
                    if($ajaxflag)
                        $pagination .= "<li><a href=javascript:ajaxPagination('".$url_name."/". $i ."/".$d."')>$i</a></li>" ;
                    else
                        $pagination .= "<li><a href='".$url_name."/". $i ."'>$i</a></li>" ;
                }   
            }
            //  NEXT & LAST links
            if($p>=1 && $p <$total_pages)
            {
                if($ajaxflag)
                {
                    $pagination .= "<li><a href=javascript:ajaxPagination('".$url_name ."/". ($p+1) ."/".$d."')>"."NEXT"."</a></li>";
                    //$pagination .= "<a href=javascript:ajaxPagination('".$url_name ."/$total_pages')>".lang("LAST")."</a>&nbsp;" ;
                }   
                else
                {
                    $pagination .= "<li><a href='".$url_name ."/". ($p+1) ."'>"."NEXT"."</a></li>";
                    //$pagination .= "<a href='".$url_name ."/$total_pages'>".lang("LAST")."</a>&nbsp;" ;
                }
            }
        }   //  if($total_pages>1) end.

        $pagination .='</ul>';
        //echo $pagination;

        return ($pagination) ;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: can you shows us Commfuncmodel file

Comment: i add my model code please check it and let me know the changes

Comment: why you can't use the inbuild codeigniter pagination library - http://www.sitepoint.com/pagination-with-codeigniter/

Comment: actually i am developing the project and i need to use existing code so that's why i am using the existing code but if you give me the idea then i will try my best to use pagination library

Comment: @OmkarHendre I suggest you convert your code to codeigniter first than you can debug faster

Comment: Actually in above code the limit_start and limit_end are working with $this->db->query()

Comment: i am using codeigniter